# Система имён пользователей сайта

Tags: mysql, sql

Возникла задача реализации поиска пользователей по имени, фамилии. Но... необходимо также учитывать уменьшительно-ласкательные формы имён. Т.е., при запросе "Саша" должны учитываться "Саша", "Шура", "Шурик", "Александр". Есть у меня идея, но хочу услышать ваше мнение, верна ли она:

Должно быть три таблицы:

```
1):
id
real_name

2):
id
real_name 
second_name 
gender

3):
id
second_name
```

Следовательно, потом поиск будет проходить по полю second_name и, в случае совпадения, в массив критериев поиска добавляются все смежные варианты. Всё так? Поправьте, пожалуйста, если не прав.

Comment: Синонимайзер, и/или выделять корень слова.. но результат вас не порадует :) вот тут посмотрите [леммы](http://lemmatise.ijs.si/Software/Version3) и [тут](http://www.solarix.ru/for_developers/api/grammar-engine-examples.shtml)

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, большое за ссылки. Но мне чтот кажется, что проще самому сделать систему синонимизации имён. Можно форму добавления синонимов имён создать для админа, и пущай сидит заполняет на полуавтомате))